# Play html5 videos in IE11 when referrer header is set to no-referrer

Tags: javascript, html, video, internet-explorer-11, referrer-policy

For some business I need to play html5 videos in IE11 in an html page having referrer meta tag is set to `no-referrer`

Here an example of code I use

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test</title>

  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268"
  data-setup='{}'>
  </video>

  <script>
    const player = videojs('my_video_1');
    player.src({
      src: 'http://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8',
      type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The video plays fine if remove referrer meta tag.
I've tried multiple html5 video players that works in IE11, if I add the that tag, video won't play.
Even if Youtube's website if I execute this code in the console

```js
var meta = document.createElement('meta'); 
meta.name = "referrer"; 
meta.content = "no-referrer"; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

all videos won't work
and I get this error

[image: youtube error]

Comment: maybe fix those invalid property values first?

Comment: that error appears when I add that meta tag

Comment: After some debugging I figure out the problem is related to URL.createObjectURL function. there is an issue with this function when "no-referrer" is set

Answer (score 0):

Please check [the Referrer-Policy Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy), the IE 11 browser support partial referrer policy: *"Supports an older draft of the specification with **never**, **always**, **origin** & **default** values."* And, when using the video.js in IE browser, it needs to send the referrer information, so, you could try to change the value to `default` or `always`.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="default" />
```

More detail information about the Referrer-Policy Directives, please check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy).